# Python における `'NoneType' object has no attribute '__getitem__'` というエラーについて

Tags: python, sqlite

画像のエラーはいったいどうすれば解決できるのでしょうか？  
調べた結果属性に問題があるようですがよくわからなかったため質問しました。

ソースコードは以下に記載します。

よろしくお願いします。

```
import sys, getopt
import sqlite3

class Location:

    def __init__(self, filename=""):
        self.filename = filename
        self.locations = list()

    def seek(self):
        if self.filename=="":
            return False

        file = open(self.filename,"r")

        for line in file:
            line_sep=line.split("\t")
            if( len(line_sep) > 2 ):
                if(line_sep[1] == "LOC"):
                   time     = line_sep[2].split(',')[0]
                   latitude = line_sep[2].split(',')[1]
                   longitude= line_sep[2].split(',')[2]

                   location = {'time':time, 'latitude':latitude, 'longitude':longitude}
                   self.locations.append(location)
        return True

    def printAll(self):
        if(len(self.locations) > 0):
            print 'time, latitude, longitude'
        for location in self.locations:
            print location['time'], location['latitude'], location['longitude']  

class Audio:

    def __init__(self, filename=""):
        self.filename = filename
        self.startTime = 0.0
        self.stopTime = 0.0

    def seek(self):
        if self.filename=="":
            return False

        file = open(self.filename,"r")

        for line in file:
            line_sep=line.split()
            if( len(line_sep) > 2 ):
                if(line_sep[1] == "AUDIO"):
                    if(line_sep[2] == "start"):
                        self.startTime = line_sep[0]
                    elif(line_sep[2] == "stop"):
                        self.stopTime = line_sep[0]

        return True

    def printTime(self):
        print self.startTime, self.stopTime

    def getDuration(self):
        return (float(self.stopTime) - float(self.startTime))


class FileManager:
    def __init__(self, filename, database):
        #database connection
        self.conn = sqlite3.connect(database)
        self.cur = self.conn.cursor()
        self.filename = filename

        # filename must be separated by '-'. (e.g. hasc-20120527-115511-raw.log)
        self.idname = '-'.join(filename.split("-")[0:3])

    def _getFileinfoId(self):
        self.cur.execute("select fileinfo.id from files inner join fileinfo on files.id=fileinfo.fileId where files.filename like '" + self.idname + "%'")
        return self.cur.fetchone()[0]

    def updateDatabase(self):
        fileinfoId = str(self._getFileinfoId())
        audio = Audio(self.filename)
        audio.seek()

        self.cur.execute("update fileinfo set startTime='"+ audio.startTime + "' where id=" + fileinfoId )
        self.cur.execute("update fileinfo set endTime='"  + audio.stopTime  + "' where id=" + fileinfoId )
        self.conn.commit()

        loc = Location(filename = self.filename)
        loc.seek()
        for location in loc.locations:
            self.cur.execute("insert into geolocations(fileId, time, latitude, longitude) values("+ fileinfoId +", "+ location['time'] +", "+ location['latitude'] +", "+ location['longitude']+")")
            self.conn.commit()

def main(argv):
    logfile = ''
    database = ''
    try:
        opts, args = getopt.getopt(argv,"hl:d:",["log=","db="])
        if len(opts) < 1:
            raise getopt.GetoptError("")
    except getopt.GetoptError:
        print 'hascseeker.py --log <logfile> --db <databasefile>'
        sys.exit()
    for opt, arg in opts:
        if opt in ("-h", "--help"):
            print 'hascseeker.py --log <logfile> --db <databasefile>'
            sys.exit()
        elif opt in ("-l", "--log"):
            logfile = arg
        elif opt in ("-d", "--db"):
            database = arg

    man = FileManager(logfile, database)
    man.updateDatabase()

if __name__ == "__main__":
   main(sys.argv[1:])
```

[image: エラー画面]

Answer (score 2):

SQL 文の実行結果が 0 件の場合、`fetchone()` は `None` を返します。

[11.13. sqlite3 — DB-API 2.0 interface for SQLite databases](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3.Cursor.fetchone)

> Cursor.fetchone()
>
> Fetches the next row of a query result set, returning a single sequence, or None when no more data is available.

なので、以下の様に書くべきではないでしょうか。

```
def _getFileinfoId(self):
  self.cur.execute("select fileinfo.id from files inner join fileinfo on files.id=fileinfo.fileId where files.filename like '" + self.idname + "%'")
  result = self.cur.fetchone()
  return ( None if result is None else result[0] )
```

ただ、`None` の場合にはそのまま返していますので、適宜変更して下さい。

Answer (score 2):

修正方法は [**heliac2001さんの回答**](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/a/4625/728) を見ていただくとして、エラーの意味するところがわからないようですのでエラーメッセージの意味を少し。

> `'NoneType' object has no attribute '__getitem__'`

attributeは属性と訳せますが、このエラーの意味として平たく言えばメソッドとかプロパティの事です。

「(`__getitem__`を呼び出すような処理だが) `__getitem__` というメソッドとかプロパティの類を持っていませんよ」という意味になります。

最初の `'NoneType' object` は None型のオブジェクトです。変数の中身が（文字とか数値とかでなく、Noneだった）ということです。

まとめる（というほどでもないですが）と、
「問題となった行では、None型なオブジェクトに対して `__getitem__` を使おうとしているけど、そのオブジェクトは `__getitem__` というものを持っていない」

というエラーで、ちょうど以下の様なコードで発生するエラーですね。

```
sample = None
sample.__getitem__(0)
```

さて、コード中には存在しない`__getitem__` はどこから来たのかという疑問が生まれますが、これはpythonが内部で呼び出す特殊なメソッド（magic method)です。

`varname[0]` というようにコンテナ変数にアクセスすると、内部では pythonが`__getitem__`メソッドを暗黙に呼び出します。（magic methodはpythonが内部で呼び出すものなので通常ユーザーが勝手に呼び出してよいものではありません。）

```
Python 2.7.8 (default, Jun 30 2014, 16:03:49) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> a = ['x','y']
>>> a[0]
'x'
>>> a.__getitem__(0)             <- getitemでも同じように取得できる。
'x'

>>> b = { 'a': 'A', 'b': 'B' }
>>> b['a']
'A'
>>> b.__getitem__('a')           <- getitemでも同じように取得できる。
'A'
>>> b.__getitem__('b')
'B'
```

`__xxxx__` なスタイルの記述がエラーに現れたら名前からやろうとしていることを想像してみるといいかもしれません。

`self.cur.fetchone()[0]`で、`fetchone()` が `None`を返すので `None[0]` となり、None型から0番目のアイテムを取り出そうとしてエラーとなっているわけです。

と、説明してみましたがあまりわかりやすくなってないかもしれませんね(^^;

Comment: ご説明、どうもありがとうございます。質問された方の事をもっと考えるべきでした。。